# How far into a service panel can sheathed cable extend?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, code-compliance

Below is a crop of an image posted in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/245537/electric-panel-common-wire). Ignoring all the other issues in the original question:

- Is having the NM-B sheathing running all the way up to the red arrow code legal?
- If it's legal, is it considered "neat and workman like" or should it have been cut back to near where the green arrow points?

*Note that the cable below where the green arrow points seems to come into the panel here and exits elsewhere, uncut, from the panel, so isn't part of this question.*

[image: Panel wiring in question]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

Comment: Can see some people would like the extra protection of the the cover to prevent hot wires touching the grounds, but do not know if it is code.

Comment: If the hots are properly insulated, @crip659 and aren't stripped too far back from their attachment point on the breaker (i.e., properly insulated), I don't see how that could be a problem.

Comment: Perhaps https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/111204/do-you-strip-the-outer-sheath-on-romex-when-it-enters-a-load-center-breaker-bo but keep in mind your box fill

Comment: That indeed answers my question, @P2000. Thanks.

Comment: I have no problem with it, if anything it's a good place to sharpie on *where the cable goes*. By the way, leaving enough wire length for rearrangement is one thing this installer got right.

Comment: "one thing", @Harper-ReinstateMonica or "_the_ one thing"? ;)